# Variable modified in an ajax request is not visible after having been executed

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables, jquery

My variable is Global, but she doesn't display the same result :

```
function checkLiveRdv(salle, jour, dateus, heure)
{
var resu;
   var urlaction = myUrl;

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: urlaction,
      data: myDatas,
      success: function(message)
      {

         data = $.parseJSON(message);
         if(data['nb']==1)
            resu = "ok";
         else resu = "pasok";
         //this alert display the good result
         alert (resu);

      }
   });
   //this alert display 'undefined', why ???
   alert(resu);
}
```

I don't know why resu doesn't keep the data :/

Comment: You variable isn't a real global, it is defined within a function with 'var' so it is a local (for the function) variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is becouse you are not waiting for the `$.ajax()` call to complete.

If you need synchronous requests, set the sync option to false:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

First, your `resu` variable is not global. It is local inside the scope of the `checkLiveRdv` function. Global variables in javascript are declared without the `var` keyword. However, omitting global variables is a good practice.

The first alert which appears displays a yet valueless undefined `resu`. The asynchronous `$.ajax` finishes later and as it fills the value of `resu`, it gets displayed correctly.

I would leave the ajax call asynchronous as it is now. And work with `resu` only inside the ajax callback as it gets its value inside it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `$.ajax()` in this case is asynchronous. Modify `$.ajax()` to include `async: false`:

```
   $.ajax( {
      type    : 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url     : urlaction,
      data    : myDatas,
      async   : false,
      success : function(message) {
         data = $.parseJSON(message);
         if(data['nb']==1)
            resu = "ok";
         else resu = "pasok";
            alert (resu);
      }
   } );
```